# Advise for best query performance (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for the best MySQL query for that situation:

I'm listing 10 last posts of a member.

```
table for posts:
post_id | uid | title | content | date
```

The member have the possibility to subscribe to other member posts, so that posts are listed in the same list (sorted by date - same table)

So it's ok to select last posts of userid X and userid Y
But I'd like to allow members to diable display of some posts (the ones he doesn't want to be displayed).

My problem is: how can I make that as simple as possible for MySQL?... I thought about a second table where I put the post ids that the user doesn't want:

```
table postdenied
uid | post_id
```

Then make a select like:

```
select * from posts as p where not exists (select 1 from postdenied as d where d.post_id = p.post_id and d.uid = p.uid) order by date DESC limit 10
```

I'm right?
 Or is there something better?

Thanks

Comment: why are you getting all the posts if you only need the last 10?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forgot the "order by date DESC limit 10"

Comment: Why you not use `JOIN`?

Comment: Does the `posts.uid` column store the poster's id?

Comment: The structure I gave was an idea, perhap's there is a much more efficient structure/tables?

Comment: Given your comments, it's actually unclear what you're asking for here.

Comment: I just ask what is the best solution to make this function : user can remove a post from its listing. I need table structures and queries for best performance.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, the `posts.uid` column stores the ID of the poster. And the `postdenied.uid` stores the ID of the user that doesn't want to see a certain post.

If the above assumptions are correct, then your query is fine, except that you should not join on the `uid` columns, only on the `post_id` ones. And you should have a parameter or constant the userID (noted as `@X` in the code below) of the user that you want to show all the posts - except those he has "denied":

```
select p.* 
from posts as p 
where not exists 
      (select 1 
       from postdenied as d 
       where d.post_id = p.post_id 
         and d.uid = @X             -- @X is the userID of the specific user
      )                                 
order by date DESC 
limit 10 ;
```

Comment: No, I must join on uid too, because one post can be denied by several members on their blog... And the structure I gave was an idea, perhap's there is a much more efficient structure/tables?

Comment: @Recif: Can you describe what you want the query to return? All posts-users combinations? All posts (or the newest 10) that a specific user would like  to see (my answer)? The posts that all users do like? Something else? Either describe it or give us sample data and sample wanted result set.

Comment: I'd like users to be able to remove posts from others that he doesn't want to see on his blog. So juste remove from listing. There is a lot of users/blogs.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach to implementing this would be with a `LEFT JOIN` clause.

```
SELECT * FROM posts AS p 
  LEFT JOIN postdenied as d ON d.post_id = p.post_id and d.uid = p.uid
WHERE d.uid IS NULL
ORDER BY date DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

It's unclear to me whether this would be more amenable to the query optimizer. If you have a large amount of data, it may be worth testing both queries and seeing if one is more performant than the other.

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be7e3/1

*Appreciation to ypercube and Lamak for their feedback on my original answer*

Comment: What's weird about `NOT EXISTS`?

Comment: And the query (both the OP's and yours) are not joins. They are [antijoins (and often called anti-semijoins)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Antijoin_.28.E2.96.B7.29).

Comment: What's weird is that the OP is attempting a table join (and yes... they *are* table joins... the term 'antijoin' is part of relational algebra, not the SQL spec), without using a `JOIN` clause. This is unnecessary obfuscation, adds an unnecessary `SELECT` and is quite probably confusing the query optimizer

Comment: Not sure what your point is. Yes, antijoin is a term of relational algebra. Yes, `JOIN` is an SQL keyword. So is `EXISTS`. I can't figure why you say that a correlated `NOT EXISTS` subquery is more weird than a `LEFT JOIN` + `IS NULL` check. For me, the second seems more unnatural but that's personal opinion. Both writings are among the most common ways to write an antijoin in SQL. And the optimizer is not confused at all. It usually produces the same or similar plans.

Comment: Do you think that using `EXISTS` can confuse the query optimizer?, and you even said *quite probably*, have any data to back that up?

Comment: hmmm... I'm not sure how to proceed here. You're both correct. I ran this through `EXPLAIN` and it looks like the optimizer actually adds a 'Not exists'.
So, my answer is a function of my ignorance of other ways to implement an antijoin. I could delete it... or I could modify it into an 'anti-answer' along the lines of "Don't believe that this is a superior method"

Comment: I also wanted to feedback my appreciation for your comments... I'd rather be downvoted and learn something the blunder on in ignorance.

Comment: @Dancrumb not a problem at all. And you might even be right about the performance of `LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL` versus `NOT EXISTS` on MySQL (http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/). My comment was about `EXISTS` confusing the optimizer.

Comment: @Dancrumb You can edit that this is another way to write the query. And it could be more efficient in some (or many) cases, so don't delete it. It really depends on so many things and with MySQL, it never hurts to try many different ways of running queries.